# Создание Vector3 с передачей одного параметра

Tags: unity3d

Возможна ли инициализация `Vector3` с указанием одного параметра этого же типа, чтобы не писать подобных конструкций:

```
vec = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Comment: Что означает "с указанием одного параметра этого же типа"? Вообще Vector3 обычно только через три параметра указывается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, значит, задать значение переменной, передав туда только `transform.position`. Не обязательно в конструктор, если есть другие методы для этого, не буду против них. Функция задания значения с параметром типа `Vector3`.

Comment: Вам нужно скопировать вектор? В интернетах пишут, что можно просто присвоить старое значение новой переменной. Они будут независимы. https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-copy-clone-a-vector3.89358/

Comment: @КириллМалышев, спасибо. Почему-то думал, что копируются по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Переменные могут передаваться по ссылке, либо нет - по значению.
Переменная типа данных float передается по значению, то есть при таком коде:

```
float a = 5.1f;
float b = a;
a = 6.2f;
```

Переменная b так и останется равна 5.1.

Vector3 (и Vector2, и Vector2Int, и Vector3Int...) является, грубо говоря, набором из 2/3/... чисел типа int/float. Таким образом при таком коде:

```
Vector3 a = new Vector3(1,1,1);
Vector3 b = a; // Можно указать new Vector3(a.x, a.y, a.z), но это сумасшествие
a = new Vector3(2,2,2);
```

Переменная b так и останется равной new Vector3(1,1,1)

Answer (score 0):

`Vector3` это структура (`struct`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура ведёт себя как **базовые типы** (`int`, `float`, `bool`, `string` и т.д.).

`new Vector3()` похоже на конструктор класса, лишь потому, что так удобно указать поля одной строчкой, а не множеством.

```
Vector3 MyVector;
MyVector.x = 1; // не удобно
MyVector.y = 2; // явно трешак
MyVector.z = 3; // но с структурами можно и так
```

Структура хоть и обладает методами, но это не класс и ему не нужен конструктор.

Как и базовые типы, структура не ссылочный тип.

```
int MyIntA = 3;
int MyIntB = MyIntA; // не ссылается, а копирует
Vector3 MyVectorA = new Vector3(1, 2, 3); // не инициализирует, а копирует
Vector3 MyVectorB = MyVectorA; // не ссылается, а копирует
Vector3 MyVectorC = transform.position; // не ссылается, а копирует
```

Как и базовые типы, структуры могут обрабатывать математические и логические операторы (перегрузка операторов), в чём их фишка.

```
Vector3 MyVectorD = MyVectorA+MyVectorB;
Vector3 MyVectorE = MyVectorC*2f;
Vector3 MyVectorF = new Vector3(1, 2, 3)-new Vector3(3, 2, 1);
Vector3 MyVectorG = transform.position*0.5f+new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
if (MyVectorA > MyVectorB)
// Vector3 не обрабатывают логические сравнения > и <, но структуры так могут уметь в отличае от классов
```